# How I Can Use For Loop With Array And Get value One By One By Clicking

Tags: javascript, html

Please, I want some help.
I want to use for-loop with array and i want to get values one by one using button.

- I want on click and get --> "A",
- when i click again and get --> "B",
- when i click again and get --> "C"
- ...

When i use for loop i get only the last value
you can see and edit the code [here](https://repl.it/@saidkot/Ask-For-Loop).

**How can I use for-loop with an array and get value one by one by clicking:**

```
var myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

var display = document.getElementById("display");
var x = 0;

function oneByOne() {
    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    display.innerHTML = myArray[i]; // Result => "F"
 }
}
```

**Like the following code:**

```
display.innerHTML = myArray[0];

function oneByOne() {
 x++;
 if (x < myArray.length) {
   display.innerHTML = myArray[x];

} else {
   display.innerHTML = "End";
 }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<h1 id="display"></h1>
<button onclick="oneByOne()"> One By One </button>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I want to get the value from array one by one, but i get only the last one

Comment: check code here https://repl.it/@saidkot/Ask-For-Loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `while` loop is easier to use for a *"one-by-one"* operation than a `for` loop. Either way loops continue to iterate through the array until the end -- so you need to pause or stop the loop so you when you click it shows only one iteration. You also have to remember where you are in the loop by having the increment declared outside the loop (or your case outside the function) so it doesn't get reset back to 0. BTW you declared `x=0` outside the function (good) but then you have global `i` variable (no `var`) inside loop instead (bad).

The first example is a `while` loop. Note the `break` breaks the loop allowing the callback function to catch each loop. The second example is a `for` loop. Instead of a `break` returning whatever is in the loop stops it. The way it's remembering where it is in the loop is by incrementing the index within the brackets of the array as it is being returned.

```js
const array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

////////////  X1 BY WHILE LOOP //////////////
const button1 = document.querySelector('.button1');
const display1 = document.querySelector(".display1");

let x1 = 0;

function oneByOne1(e) {
  while (x1 < array.length) {
    display1.innerHTML = array[x1];
    break;
  }
  x1++
}

button1.onclick = oneByOne1;

////////////  X1 BY FOR LOOP ////////////////
const button2 = document.querySelector('.button2');
const display2 = document.querySelector(".display2");

let x2 = 0;

function oneByOne2(e) {
  for (x2; x2 < array.length; x2++) {
    return display2.innerHTML = array[x2++];
  }
}

button2.onclick = oneByOne2;
```

```css
:root {
  font-family: Consolas
}
```

```html
<button class='button1'>X1</button> while loop...X1: <output class='display1'></output><br>
<button class='button2'>X2</button> for loop.....X2: <output class='display2'></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after your clarification here is working code:

```js
var myArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"];

var display = document.getElementById("display");

var x = 0;

function oneByOne() {
  if (x < myArray.length) {
    display.innerHTML = myArray[x];
  } else {
    display.innerHTML = "End";
  }
  x++;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="display"></h1>
<button onclick="oneByOne()"> One By One </button>
```

Comment: i want on click get "A", when i click again get "B", when i click again get "C" ....

Comment: @saidkot ok, edited my answer according to your comment

Comment: @saidkot a For loop does not wait for a button to be pressed on every cycle.